# Keep a nodeJS server app to the LAN

Tags: node.js, networking, server, lan

I code a little app in nodeJS that now listen on port 3000 to access it through multiple devices, with this line: `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);`.

I don't know anything about networking yet, and I wonder at what level of accessibility my server is open with this kind of code.

Everyone over the Internet? 
Neighbors who use the same internet provider?
My Wi-Fi?

Even if I miss the point here, would you tell me how to ensure a simple nodeJS server app access is limited to near devices?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of accessibility your server allows depends on where you run your server on and what port you run it on.

For example if you are running your server on your local machine, anyone in your local network (everyone who is connected to your router) can access your server through `<YOUR_LOCAL_IP>:3000`

You can find your LAN ip through System Preferences > Network on MacOS. Or open your terminal and use `arp -a`.

If you are running your application on a server from a provider like Digital Ocean for example, they would provide you with a public ip. And you can access your app trough that ip and the port you are running your app on.

Web applications run on port 80 since that is the default port for http. (or 443 if https). When you make a request to a www.google.com for example, you actually make a request to port 80.

But if you still want to run your app on port 3000, you can still do but then you would have to specify the port as well. For example if www.google.com was running on port 3000, `wwww.google.com:3000` would work fine.

Comment: So if i run my server with the public ip of my computer (the one you see when you tip 'ip' in google search), everyone can potentially access it ?

Comment: the problem is, when I run this: `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);`  , the server is accessible from the PUBLIC ip. How to avoid this?

Comment: No it is not available through public ip. Read about networking here: http://openbookproject.net/courses/intro2ict/networking/intro.html

Comment: Thanks I will read that. So its not available from the exterior of my lan even if this command make the server listen on my_public_ip:3000 (its my public ip I need to tip in the browser to access the ressource)?

Comment: Also, I find out you can specified an ip to listen to. So I'll use my lan ip instead of my public ip (tell me if it has no importance) by precaution: `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '192.168.1.111');`